# route in graph with specific length from one point

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a method "connection(int n)" which gives me all the cells number that have relation with cell number "n" now I want a method which gives me all the routes with a specific length "myLength" that start from cell number "start" and just in one direction (as it's usual) I mean we are not allowed to pass some cells more than one time
thanks in advance for your help
P.S. I can't use map tools, graph tools,... with basic tools please

Comment: So... you "want" a method? That's interesting...

Comment: Given a source vertex $v$ and a length $l,$ Breadth-First Search gives you all vertices on the frontier $l$ edges away from $v.$

Comment: Oh. You guys don't have LaTeX on MO..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Model your problem as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) `G = (V,E)` such that `V = {1,...,n}` [all possible values] and `E = { (u,v) | connection(u) returns v }` [there is a connection between u and v using your `connection()` method]

In addition to the standard BFS, you will need to add another stop condition when you reached the limited length.

**EDIT:**

Note that this solution assumes you are looking for a path *up-to length*, and not *exactly length*. 

BFS doesn't work here for the counter example of a [clique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_%28graph_theory%29) if you want *exactly of length*.

To get all vertices that have a simple path of *exactly length* - You will probably need a [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) that avoids loops [can be done by maintaining a `set` that is modified each iteration], but can explore each vertex more then once.

Comment: can you give the code in java please but with out using java graph utilities and map utilities, please!

Comment: I encountered with this : Click [here] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search
that's what I wanted but it uses a lot from map, graph, set, ... that I didn't want it I want a recursive function to do it ca any one help?